# Change order of custom submenu link in WP Admin?

Tags: php, customization, actions, admin-menu, add-submenu-page

I've added a custom link to WP Admin under the *Users* menu, but trouble is I can't seem to get it to display above the default options. Is this possible?

**My code:**

```
// Add sub-menu option to users menu to contractors section (shortcut)
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_add_contractors_submenu', 5);

function my_add_contractors_submenu() {
    global $submenu;
    $permalink = admin_url('users.php?role=contractor');
    $submenu['users.php'][] = array( 'Contractors', 'manage_options', $permalink );
}
```

Note that I used this method instead of `add_submenu_page` as I needed to add the link myself.

I've tried playing around with the `priority` parameter in the `add_action` but it won't go any higher - I'm trying to get it to display as the second option, just under " All Users".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this function.

```
function my_submenu_order($menu_ord) {
    global $submenu;

    // echo '<pre>'.print_r($submenu,true).'</pre>';

    $arr = array();
    $arr[] = $submenu['users.php'][15]; // Your Profile
    $arr[] = $submenu['users.php'][10]; // Add New
    $arr[] = $submenu['users.php'][5]; // All Users
    $submenu['users.php'] = $arr;

    return $menu_ord;
}

add_filter('custom_menu_order', 'my_submenu_order');
```

Add that to your functions.php. It changes the default order of the user's submenu from [5] [10] [15].

Now un-comment the echo and comment out everything else.  This will output the menu item positions for everything.  Look for your new submenu and add it to the list.  So it would be something like this.

```
function my_submenu_order($menu_ord) {
    global $submenu;

    // echo '<pre>'.print_r($submenu,true).'</pre>';

    $arr = array();
    $arr[] = $submenu['users.php'][15];
    $arr[] = $submenu['users.php'][##]; // Add New Number
    $arr[] = $submenu['users.php'][10];
    $arr[] = $submenu['users.php'][5];
    $submenu['users.php'] = $arr;

    return $menu_ord;
}

add_filter('custom_menu_order', 'my_submenu_order');
```

---

**EDIT**

The above code works fine BUT if you were to add a plugin later that adds links to the Users submenu they wouldn't show up because we are wiping out the original menu and not including the new links (because we don't know what they are).

If that is a concern, instead of wiping out the menu we can add the newly sorted items to the end and remove the originals.  See below.

```
function my_submenu_order($menu_ord) {
    global $submenu;

    // echo '<pre>'.print_r($submenu,true).'</pre>';

    // Build array of newly sorted items
    $arr = array();
    $arr[] = $submenu['users.php'][15]; // Your Profile
    $arr[] = $submenu['users.php'][10]; // Add New
    $arr[] = $submenu['users.php'][5]; // All Users

    // Remove the originals
    unset($submenu['users.php'][15]);
    unset($submenu['users.php'][10]);
    unset($submenu['users.php'][5]);

    // Add newly items to the list
    $submenu['users.php'] += $arr;

    return $menu_ord;
}

add_filter('custom_menu_order', 'my_submenu_order');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this - but question, does this prevent new items being added to the submenu, by plugins for example? ...as wouldn't they need to be added to this function, or is this simply reordering things?

Comment: Submenu items not included in that list will not show up.  You can test this by commenting out one of the default links.  I think it would work the same if you a plugin where to create one, depending on when this happens.

Comment: Ahh, not very ideal then as it would break functionality.

Comment: It would only effect users submenu. You would have to test it if you plan on adding a plug-in that will add a submenu to users

Comment: It's the best option I've seen

Comment: Trouble is, it's for a clients site, so I don't have control over what plugins they decide to add after the fact.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure if it's even an issue. When I get time I'll have to test with a plug-in

Comment: OK.  I used a plugin called WP User Manager to test, it adds links to the users submenu. They were not getting added because of the way I was overriding the menu.  I edited my answer to include a fix for that

Comment: It's important to note that the keys from the re-added array elements lose their keys using this method; additionally, I had to re-order the keys when adding them, as in I added `$arr[] = $submenu['users.php'][5];` first in the code rather than last.